# blob extracting using opencv

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, image-processing, opencv

I had done cvAdaptiveTheshold function for getting the below output image. Now I want to crop the image area which contains the three rows A,B and C. All other elements needs to be removed. I think blob is a best method to do that. I got all the blobs with specific areas and perimeter. I think removing the blobs according to the sizes is not a good method. Then, how can we get that specific area's blobs together? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.[image: image that should be processed]

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, you'd notice that the three rows you want are bounded above and below by dashed horizontal lines. Without going into text detection of blobs, you could do it thus:

1. Apply a horizontal long structuring element with morphological erosion on the image will join the dashed lines into two single lines.
2. Check the aspect ratio and length of each blob to know which are the two lines
3. For each of the other blobs, check its position w.r.t. the two lines - if bounded vertically then select.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I didnt have that dashed lines always.

Answer (score 0):

use cvblob on your processed image.

http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/